# Get month from interval datatype

Tags: oracle

I have a column with `interval year to month` datatype. With `Extract` function I get only month value from interval. But how to get full month (year * 12 + month)?

I can use `Extract` for year, multiply it by 12 and add it to the extracted month. But how to do it simply, using 1 function?

Comment: Asking for `(year * 12 + month)` is quite special, why do expect a simpler build-in function? `Extract(year from ym) + 12*Extract(month from ym)` is rather simple.

Comment: but I access the same column twice. Imagine another example: column is of type 'interval day to second'. To take the value in minutes, I need to access one column 4 times, and even round off seconds

Comment: Yes, and where is the problem? You don't read the value four times from disk - we are talking about nanoseconds which are needed for this calculation.

Comment: Wernfried, I found one solution. And I think its very good solution:
`select (sysdate + some_interval_value - sydate) * 86400 from some_table`